# Custom response message which validates all required parameters in Node js

Tags: node.js, express, response

I'm new to NodeJS and Express and I want to validate APIs parameters.
For now I validate parameters by:

```
if(!req.body.parametername)
    return res.send({"message": "Please provide parametername"});

if(!req.body.parametername)
    return res.send({"message": "parametername can not be blank"});
```

But I want the response to be like:

```
{
    "username": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "password": [
        "This field can not be blank."
    ]
}
```

This is the response I want if the parameters are invalid or not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) to be what you need here.
In particular this section:

```js
req.assert('email', 'required').notEmpty();
req.assert('email', 'valid email required').isEmail();
req.assert('password', '6 to 20 characters required').len(6, 20);

var errors = req.validationErrors(); // Or req.asyncValidationErrors();
var mappedErrors = req.validationErrors(true); // Or req.asyncValidationErrors(true);
```

mappedErrors will look like this:

```js
{
  email: {
    param: "email",
    msg: "valid email required",
    value: "<received input>"
  },
  password: {
    param: "password",
    msg: "6 to 20 characters required",
    value: "<received input>"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me a lot.